# Can BB-8 and other similarly round astro-mech droids swim/propel under water?

Tags: star-wars, droids, bb-8

Recently, while looking at a BB-8 toy online, I read this on their [website](https://support.sphero.com/article/9y9vwqfsjn-is-bb-8-waterproof):

> BB-8 is made to be water resistant, but we would not recommend taking your droid for a swim if it can be helped.

This actually made me wonder: in *Star Wars* canon, **can BB-8 and other similarly round astro-mech droids swim/propel under water?**

As stated, I obviously prefer answers based on canon, but well sourced answers from legends could also be acceptable.

Comment: R2-D2 works underwater

Comment: Working for a while underwater like R2-D2 did in Dagobah and swimming/propelling are different things ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upon consulting the canon animated series *Star Wars Resistance*, set in the months before *The Force Awakens*, the audience sees the BB unit **CB-23** operate and propel herself underwater. Specifically, in the episode "No Escape: Part I," protagonist Kazuda Xiono holds on to CB-23 and she propels him through the water. It isn't exactly clear how it happens, but the droid is able to swim and do an assortment of things no problem in the water (as you can see from the image and video below).

[image: Kazuda Xiono holds on to CB-23 as she propels him through the water]

Comment: I just watched the episode last night. There were several shots of CB-23 shooting out air from various vents to move around in the water